# Calling parent scope function from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I am creating a directive that opens an angular bootstrap UI modal window. When closing the modal i would like to have a function executed that is passed from the attribute on the directive.. Here is what i have so far:

This is on the index.tpl.html :

```
<popup class="something" .. on-close="update()"></popup>
```

Directive code, only scope definition since there is a lot of code prior to this:

```
scope: {
         onClose: "&"
       },
link: function(scope, element, attr){
          //some code    
          ......
          scope.closeFn = function(){
               scope.onClose();
         }
         //opening of the modal:
         var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                   ....
                   templateUrl: 'path/to/template.tpl.html,
                   controller: 'PopupController',
                   scope: scope,
                   ....
         });
```

In the template of the popup i have a function binded to a close button that calls a function in the 'PopupController' that calls the closeFn from the directive link function like so.

```
<button type="button" class="btn-close btn btn-large" ng-click="closePopup()">Close
    </button>
```

And in the 'PopupController' :

```
$scope.closeUploadPopup = function () {
        $scope.$parent.closeFn();
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
```

As far as i understand the scope.onClose() should execute the function specified by the on-close attribute?

I have not provided a lot of code since there is a lot of the original code, but i can add more if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper API [$modal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) service provides. Thus, `modalInstance` has a property `promise` which you can use to "subscribe" to get notified when popup closed ("Ok" button) or dismissed ("Cancel" button).

```
scope: {
    onClose: "&"
},
link: function(scope, element, attr) {
    // ... some code       
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        // ....
        templateUrl: 'path/to/template.tpl.html',
        controller: 'PopupController',
        scope: scope,
        // ....
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function() {
        scope.onClose(); // close handler
    }, function() {
        // dismiss handler
    });

};
```

And in popup template use `$close` and `$dismiss` methods:

```
<button type="button" class="btn-close btn btn-large" ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
```

Comment: Hi, and thank you for the kind reply! I have tried calling the function on the result promise, but still it seems that the parent function is not being called. I have tried debugging a bit, and this is what i have stumbled upon 

`destination[scopeName] = function(locals) {
              return parentGet(scope, locals);
            };`

From the angular source code

Where locals is undefined. Could it be that i am binding the function call in the wrong way?

Comment: It should work: http://plnkr.co/edit/QYC7gfbk45x6rLkZASdi?p=info Try to update this demo with your code and see if you can provide a demo with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you are assigning new `controller` to your modal popup, there is no need to assign `scope` property, which is anyway going to be ignored.

For make it working I'd suggest you to pass that method reference from the resolve of your modal popup

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'path/to/template.tpl.html',
    controller: 'PopupController',
    resolve: {
        onClose: scope.onClose
    },
    //....
});
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('PopupController', function($scope, onClose){
    $scope.closeUploadPopup = function () {
        onClose();
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
})
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply! Unfortunately with this solution i am experiencing the same behaviour as with the resopnse by @dfsq. I have mentioned a possible problem in the comment to his reply, do you think that i could be related?

Answer (score 1):

May be this dialog directive can help you.

You can customize 
1. The dialog title 
2. The message body
3. button those are displayed on the dialog and the respective action

```
<ng-dialog button="Yes|okFunction ,No|cancelFunction" dialogid="id-bootstrap" header="Angular Modal Dialog Directive " message="Hello World" theme="bootstrap">
</ng-dialog>
```

The dialog box with two button 1) Yes and 2) No will be created. the okFunction and cancelFunction are be invoked on click event. These function are defined in the controller.

**Please refer to the below link.**

http://yogeshtutorials.blogspot.in/2015/12/angular-modal-dialog-directive.html